# find selected option from group of JRadioButtons

Tags: java, radio-button, jbutton

I have a problem with my JButton in Java, I have looked it up everywhere and can't find anything to why it isn't working properly. This could help other people that have the same problem. Basically I am trying to display one of the vehicles (from a selection of JRadioButtons) in the text box saying You have selected Car for example, but when I press the "Check" button it comes up with You have selected... Null and I have no clue whatsoever.

Any help would be appreciated !

Thankyou!

Here is my code

```
    txtVehicleType = new JTextField();
    txtVehicleType.setText("Vehicle Type");
    txtVehicleType.setBounds(10, 57, 86, 20);
    frmCarpark.getContentPane().add(txtVehicleType);
    txtVehicleType.setColumns(10);


    JRadioButton rdbtnCar = new JRadioButton("Car");
    rdbtnCar.setBounds(10, 84, 51, 23);
    frmCarpark.getContentPane().add(rdbtnCar);


    JRadioButton rdbtnMotorbike = new JRadioButton("Motorbike");
    rdbtnMotorbike.setBounds(10, 110, 109, 23);
    frmCarpark.getContentPane().add(rdbtnMotorbike);

    JRadioButton rdbtnPickupTruck = new JRadioButton("Pick-up Truck");
    rdbtnPickupTruck.setBounds(10, 136, 109, 23);
    frmCarpark.getContentPane().add(rdbtnPickupTruck);

    final ButtonGroup group1 = new ButtonGroup();
    group1.add(rdbtnCar);
    group1.add(rdbtnMotorbike);
    group1.add(rdbtnPickupTruck);


    txtYouHaveSelected = new JTextField();
    txtYouHaveSelected.setText("You have selected..." );
    txtYouHaveSelected.setBounds(10, 193, 178, 29);
    frmCarpark.getContentPane().add(txtYouHaveSelected);
    txtYouHaveSelected.setColumns(10);


    JButton btnCheck = new JButton("Check");
    btnCheck.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                txtYouHaveSelected.setText("You have selected..." + group1.getSelection());

        }
    });
    btnCheck.setBounds(10, 166, 89, 23);
    frmCarpark.getContentPane().add(btnCheck);
}
```

Comment: Have you selected one of the radio buttons before clicking the Check button?

Comment: Yeah I did Azad Omer's solution fixed the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`group1.getSelection()`  Returns the model of the selected button.
You better loop inside radiobuttons and see which one is selected:

```
java.util.Enumeration<AbstractButton> rbs=buttonGroup1.getElements(); 
 while(rbs.hasMoreElements()){
       JRadioButton tempRadio = (JRadioButton)rbs.nextElement();
          if(tempRadio.isSelected()){
               System.out.println("Selected : "+tempRadio.getText());
               break;
              }
         }
```

**Note:** : `AbstractButton` used because it's defines common behaviors for buttons and menu items.

Comment: You'r welcome, add `break` after *System.out....*, because the loop won't stop until finishes checking all radiobuttons.